# How to use PGFplots to call an external data set?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the I-V-characteristics of a diode I've measured. I've got the data in a .csv file but can't figure out how to make `pgfplots` present the data. I've tried multiple examples form the internet trying to call my data but nothing seems to work.
the code i have tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    title={},


 xlabel={potential diffrence]},
ylabel={current},
xmin=-4, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
xtick={},
ytick={},


]



\addplot table{results.csv}


\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the begining of my .csv file

```
current(A),potential diffrence (V)
0.77,0.65
0.74,0.43
0.73,0.35
0.72,0.29
0.71,0.27
0.71,0.25
0.70,0.23
0.69,0.21
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In addition to showing exactly what you tried, can you show the first few lines if your `.csv` file?

Comment: I've made those changes requested

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code. First, `pgfplots` assumes whitespace delimited columns by default, so you need

```
\addplot table[col sep=comma]{results.csv};
```

to tell it to use commas. (When no column specifications are made, it uses the first column as x-values and second as y-values.)

In addition, you can't have empty lines in the optional argument to the `axis` environment, and you have to end the `\addplot` line with a semicolon.

It's also recommended to always specify a `compat` level for `pgfplots`, see section 2.2 *Upgrade remarks* in the manual. The latest version of `pgfplots` is 1.15, so I added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}`. (If your version of `pgfplots` is older, you will get an error from that, and you need to adjust it to your version. Place `\pgfplotsversion` in your document to see which version that is.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={},
  xlabel={potential diffrence]},
  ylabel={current},
  xmin=-4, xmax=1,
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
  xtick={},
  ytick={}
]
\addplot table[col sep=comma]{results.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hi thank you so much, unfortunately when i have tried to implement this i am failing to plot a large amount of my data when the y axis is equal to 0 i have a large amount of negative x axis data. is there a work around for this?

Comment: @EwenShackel I don't quite understand. You've explicitly set the axis limits, so that the x-axis goes from -4 to 1, while the y-axis runs from 0 to 1, so that is the range that is shown. If you want all the data shown, don't set the axis limits (i.e. remove `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`).

Comment: thanks. that specified region was correct. it would appear after removing the defining regions that PGFplots has used the x axis as the y axis after the 0 mark on the x axis

Comment: @EwenShackel Sorry, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: don't worry ive just had to change my data set to act how the program would like it to. so it is now working.thank you so much for your help!!!